# AppendTo con Ajax de un div específico a otro div específico

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

En el código presentado de AJAX, de la nueva hoja html descargada, intento poder seleccionar 2 elementos (etiquetados con un #id diferente cada uno) y añadirlo a otros dos #id de la hoja principal mediante `.appendTo()` (ver en las líneas al final del código).

Ejemplo:

- De la hoja `2.html`, intento agregar el contenido del div `#1` al contenido del div `#A` de la hoja `index.html`.
- De la hoja `2.html`, el div `#2` al div `#B` de `index.html`.

```js
var lazyload = lazyload || {};

(function($, lazyload) {

    "use strict";

    var page = 2,
        buttonId = "#button-more",
        loadingId = "#loading-div",
        container = "#regular";

    lazyload.load = function() {

        var url = "./" + page + ".html";

        $(buttonId).hide();
        $(loadingId).show();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(response) {
                if (!response || response.trim() == "NONE") {
                    $(buttonId).fadeOut();
                    $(loadingId).text("No more entries to load!");
                    return;
                }
                appendContests(response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                $(loadingId).text("Sorry, there was some error with the request. Please refresh the page.");
            }
        });
    };

    var appendContests = function(response) {
        var id = $(buttonId);

        $(buttonId).show();
        $(loadingId).hide();

        $(response).appendTo($(container));
        page += 1;
    };

})(jQuery, lazyload);
```

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar estos elementos específicos de la respuesta de AJAX?

Comment: Podrías mejorar el formato de la pregunta para que se entienda, poner estilo de negrita e itálica, agregar algún pequeño gráfico que muestre el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo tu código para ser honesto, no le veo relevancia a tus dudas, así que te contestaré en base a ellas.

> de la nueva hoja html descargada, y mediante .appendTo() poder seleccionar el código nuevo en 2 grupos (etiquetados con un #id diferente cada uno) y añadirlo a otros dos #id de la hoja principal

Si obtienes una plantilla lo que puedes hacer es crear un documento. Esto puedes hacerlo con [document.implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation):

```
// response es el HTML obtenido
const page2 = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
$(page2).html(response);
```

Una vez creado el documento ya puedes seleccionar cualquier etiqueta.

> De la hoja 2.html el contenido del div #2 se añadirán al contenido del div #B de la hoja index.html De la hoja 2.html los el contenido del div #1 se añadirá al contenido del div #A.

```
// #1 -> #B y #2 -> #A respectivamente
$(page2).find('#B').html($('#1').html());
$(page2).find('#A').html($('#2').html());
```